# Backup entire linux system with tar to the partition that mounted in system itself

Tags: backup, tar

All of my operating systems are mounted on one partition, it's `/dev/vda1`.

Is there problem if I backup the entire Linux directory with this command

```
root@myOS:/# tar -cJpf /mnt/bax/myOS.tar.xz .
```

Basically I backup the entire system and save it on my second partition.

Where `/mnt/bax` has been mounted by `/dev/vda2` (second partition).

I'm afraid that a recursive backup will happen, I mean since `/dev/vda2` is mounted, does that mean a recursive backup will happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably don't want to back up mounted and pseudo filesystems;
at least not `/proc`, `/sys`, `/tmp`, etc. 
So use `--one-file-system`.

You can add additional mounted filesystems if you want.

```bash
root@myOS:/# tar --one-file-system --acls --xattrs --numeric-owner -JpScf /mnt/bax/myOS.tar.xz . /media/additional-mounted-drive
```

Or you can use `--exclude` to ignore directories:

```bash
root@myOS:/# tar --acls --xattrs --numeric-owner --exclude=mnt --exclude=proc --exclude=sys --exclude=tmp -JpScf /mnt/bax/myOS.tar.xz .
```

Comment: This will be best answer if you explain flag ```acls```, ```xatrrs```, and ```numeric-owner```. Yes there's explanation in ```man tar```. But  people maybe love simple explanation

Comment: @[genpfault](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/435747): (1) You should ***add*** new information, not *replace* existing (correct) information.  (2) Everybody who uses `tar` knows what `cf` means.  (3) There’s only one **`-`** in `preserve-permissions` (i.e.,  `preserve--permissions` is wrong).  (4) If you’re going to split a long command into multiple lines, you should indent the continuation lines…  (5) … and either put each option on a line by itself, or break the command into lines short enough that horizontal scrolling is not needed.  Don’t mix styles. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … ISTM that 92 characters will fit; if you want to be safe, use 80.  (6) Putting **`.`** on a line by itself is excessive, especially in the first command.  (7) Showing the ``--xz`` option without explaining what it means does not make the answer clearer.

Answer (score 2):

I've used this one a few times. I RSYNC system to a local folder (other partition) and exclude. Then you and TAR compress it, if you want.

```
mkdir /backup1; time rsync -aAXv -h --exclude={/backup*,/dev,/home,/lost+found,/media,/mnt,/mnt2,/proc,/run,/sys,/tmp,/var/lib/lxcfs,/var/lib/lxd/unix.socket} / /backup1
```

Verify the excluded folders and add/remove what fits your system.

Then you can just TAR the backup1 folder.

```
tar czfp --rsyncable UbuntuServer1604.tar.gz ./backup1
```

OR install and use a parallel high compression codec like *lbzip2* or a faster one like *pgiz*

```
apt install lbzip2 -y && time tar cf backup1.tar.bz2 ./backup1 --use-compress-program=lbzip2
```

I played around with just using TAR for backup but prefer RSYNC. TAR does have compression options like parallel 'lbzip2' and 'pigz':
small compressed file lbzip2 or fast with pigz -k; possible sync issues? lbzip4 if error debian?

Compressed TAR files is placed on the / but you should save to your choice of folder and make sure to add that to the exclude list.

```
apt install lbzip2 -y; sudo time tar cpf backup1.tar.bz2 --exclude={/backup*,/dev,/home,/lost+found,/media,/mnt,/mnt2,/proc,/run,/sys,/tmp,/var/lib/lxcfs,/var/lib/lxd/unix.socket} --use-compress-program=lbzip2 / 

apt install pigz -y; sudo time tar cpf backup3.pigz.tar.gz --exclude={/backup*,/dev,/home,/lost+found,/media,/mnt,/mnt2,/proc,/run,/sys,/tmp,/var/lib/lxcfs,/var/lib/lxd/unix.socket} --use-compress-program=”pigz -k” /
```

Either way this is an easy way to add folders to exclude for live backups.

```
--exclude={/backup*,/dev,/home,/lost+found,/media,/mnt,/mnt2,/proc,/run,/sys,/tmp,/var/lib/lxcfs,/var/lib/lxd/unix.socket}
```

Comment: (1) This assumes that there is enough free space to make two copies of the filesystem of interest, as it makes a copy of the filesystem and then makes a backup of that.  (2) Even if it does work, this approach of reading and writing everything twice seems very non-optimal.  (But, if your root partition is less than half full, maybe you don’t care that your backup takes twice as long as it should.)  (3) Your first command can, in principle, be run anywhere.  Your second command must be run from the root directory.  You should change `./backup1` to `/backup1`.